# why angular pattern regex not working in html by work well in typescript

Tags: regex, angular

*Hi, Anyone can explain to me why regex expression in pattern property is not working*

```
  <input type="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])" minlength="6" [class.is-invalid]="passwordForm.errors && passwordForm.touched" #passwordForm="ngModel" name="password"  required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password">

 but i run in typescript it work well
 var mediumRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])");
    console.log(
      mediumRegex.test("123asA")
  );

--->true
  console.log(
    mediumRegex.test("")
);
--->false
  console.log(
    mediumRegex.test("aaaa")
--->false

); console.log(
  mediumRegex.test("1z")
);
--->true
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a consuming `.*` at the end because the HTML5 regex *must* match and consume the whole input string (due to the fact it is wrapped with `^(?:` and `)$` behind the scenes when compiling the RegExp object):

```
<input type="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*" minlength="6" [class.is-invalid]="passwordForm.errors && passwordForm.touched" #passwordForm="ngModel" name="password"  required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password">
```

The `pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*"` pattern can be improved if you replace `.*` in the lookaheads with reverse character classes:

```
pattern="(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).*"
```

See the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) in password regex validation.